# How to reduce size of XLSM that contains TABLE which is frequently added to

Tags: excel

I've got an Excel .XLSM file that contains a table with around ~8000 records. It contains 148 columns of which about 20 are calculated.
Each day an updated dataset (around 20 more than the prev day) is copied into this table, overwriting the existing records.  the file is now 180Mb.  I've temporarily deleted all but five records and the file is still 175Mb, so I'm guessing there is a temporary cache somewhere.
Is there anyway to 'flush' the temporary data to reduce the file size?

EDIT:
The WorkBook uses VBA to retrieve data from another WorkBook, but has no actual connections to any other WorkBooks

Comment: Stupid question: does it have any connection to other Workbooks?

Comment: Fastest Way to solve this (I do this): Create a new file and copy paste values from the old file to the new file. Delete the old file and use the new file. OTHER OPTION is to save the existing file as CSV and then convert it back to XLSX. You need XLSM only if you are storing macros in it. Also I am guessing that there are no formulas in the file?

Comment: Siddharth, as per the description, there is formula (~20 columns are calculated).  There is also VBA.

Comment: It would be nice if you could tell us how the problem was solved?

Comment: It's a long time a go, but the strategy I follow these days is having a 'Controller' XLSM with the VBA and a 'Data' file. Where possible, bring data in programmatically (using the controller) and if you have issues with size, try creating a new data file regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the rows that contain all but the first five records, then save your file. It should be tiny.

Deleting the content in rows doesn't reset the `UsedRange` of a worksheet when it's saved. The `UsedRange` can still be storing lots of formatting for cells. You can check this by pressing `[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[End]` to go to the last used cell in a sheet.  If you have any formats that aren't `General` there is an overhead storing them.

Excel isn't very efficient keeping track of formats as you add rows.  For example, if you create a conditional format and then insert rows within the range covered by the conditional format, Excel will "break" the conditional format ranges into 3 ranges - the range down to the insertion point, the insertion range and then the range below the insertion point.

Comment: Yeah, I've had major issues with Excel 'Excel has stopped working', due, apparently to the complexity of my files, but seesm to be because of split formatting ranges.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, `[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[End]`still takes me to 8000 rows down.